# 2D convolution for matrices of same size

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, fourier-transform

I have an $N \times N$ image say $x$. Its Fourier transform is $X$, same size $N \times N$.

Now I have a mask $M$ applied to $X$. By "applied" I mean element wise multiplication.

According to convolution theorem, this is equivalent to convolving  $m$ with $x$, where $m$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $M$ and  $x$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $X$.

In this case, both $x$ and $m$ are of same size  $N \times N$. So I am wondering in this case, how do we do convolution between $x$ and $m$ ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply 2D circular convolution, if your image is large enough and your filter is small enough (at least its energy is mostly localized) you may also survive with linear convolution (with some degradations along image borders).

Comment: Thanks. Normally when the convolutional kernel is smaller, we slide the kernel throughout the entire image. In this case, how do we "slide" the large kernel through the image? Thanks.

Comment: In circular convolution you may consider your signal as connected through its borders, like a sphere and your filter is moving along the surface. You may achieve same thing if you extend your signal periodically in each direction (So that your filter does not go out of bounds when it is placed on the corner pixels of your image) then use linear convolution then get rid of the extensions (assuming image size is larger than filter's). If you want a concrete example see figure 2 in http://www.music.miami.edu/programs/mue/research/jvandekieft/jvchapter2.htm

Comment: Thanks! a lot! !!